# How can I have android "scale" my application?

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution, screen-size

I am creating my first android application and this has been driving me insane.

My application is for the android smartphones, and I only need one specific design for my layout. I do not need to change the design of the layout for each device. All I want to do is resize the layout to support all the different screen sizes and resolutions. I have tried multiple things and can't seem to get it right.

For Example:
 I have several buttons on my pages, and the buttons need to be at a specific point on the image that I have as the background. These buttons need to still be at the same point on the image even if the device's screen size was increased or the screen resolution was increased.

Just some info about my application:

-all my button locations are in DIP (one of the solutions that I tried had me do this)
-my layout XML files are in a folder titled "layout"

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Here is the code for one of my layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mybackground"

>
<Button  
android:layout_width="115dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="450dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="105dip" 
android:layout_height="50dip" 
android:id="@+id/button01"

>
</Button>

<Button  
android:layout_width="70dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="460dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="250dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip" 
android:id="@+id/button03"

>
</Button>




</RelativeLayout>
```

The code above is one of my layouts. This layout has two buttons that need to be in the same location in relation to the background "mybackground". These buttons have the transparent attribute applied to them so that elements on the image are the "buttons". This works on my Droid2, but then when applied to a screen bigger or more dense, the buttons are no longer in the correct positions in relation to the image.

Comment: Are you using the <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" /> in your AndroidManifest.xml? This matters if you're supporting 1.5 devices.

Comment: If you support only API >= 4 it's going to be much easier (you surely have read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)). However from your example it seems that you want to create an absolute layout over an image, and it's not a good idea as you're finding out.

Comment: bigstones- I am finding that you are right. I have read the Supporting Multiple Screens article, and that is where I learned about the dip. I want the users to be able to run the app up to the latest version of android so that all android users can work with it. However, we are gearing the app to work for smartphone users instead of tablet users. Since we want mainly phone users, we will probably not be going higher than Android 2.3

Comment: Your layout isn't actually using any of the RelativeLayout alignment capabilities, you're just using margins to position things in pixels. dips as a unit of measurement are not a way to treat devices as if they have the same resolution, they're a way to deal with devices that have very different pixel densities when sizing elements.

Answer (score 2):

What adamp is saying in his comment on Rollin_s's question is: What is the reason for you needing the buttons to be over a specific spot on the background? If that spot is another image (for example) that needs to be aligned, make that image its own ImageView and align the button with RelativeLayout parameters. Maybe if you included a screenshot, someone could give you a better example of what to do. Also, GridView and TableLayout are good objects for aligning layout components to fit different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I am developing this application for someone. They have these UI images pre-built because they are also working with an iPhone version. I am taking the images and using them as the background, and laying transparent buttons on top of the graphical UI. This works, and I have finished the UI. The problem I am running into is that the background image (which IS the graphical UI) fills the screen no matter what size, however the buttons are misplaced if the screen is not the same as my Droid2.

Comment: I am more familiar with the iPhone SDK, and have developed several applications for it already. When creating an iPhone app, I create the interface however I want and the OS will make the app scale when run on the iPhone 4, which is more dense than the 3G and 3GS. This also works on iPad, the OS runs it in a "windowed" mode or will scale it up to closer to the iPad screen size. I would like to do a similar thing with this android app. I cannot seem to find anything as far as the OS scaling for me, but I don't mind adding the code myself if there is such code out there for devs to use.

Comment: The iPhone 4's resolution was selected because it can perfectly double pixels when scaling a UI built for older devices. There is far more diversity in Android device resolutions and simply scaling to something other than a multiple of the original design's resolution produces ugly artifacts at best and aspect ratio skew at worst. You can do it, it's not difficult, but the results will be very sloppy on many devices. Pixel-perfect aligning UI elements with a background image is not a viable way to build a good UI on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try Relative Layout:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Thank you for both answers! I am using the <supports-screens> code and I am already using the relative layout. However, I tried the same version of my application on both the Atrix 4G and the Droid 2 (which have slightly different screens) and the buttons were in different spots. Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Throw out the idea of matching on-screen elements against pixel-perfect locations on the background. It's not going to work when resolutions and aspect ratios differ from device to device. Your background is probably emulating other visual elements meant to tie your UI together. Can you break it up into elements that can live in different views positioned by a RelativeLayout or similar?

Comment: adamp,I'm not sure I follow what you are talking about. I'm going to post the code for one of my layouts on here so you all can see what I'm talking about doing. I may be doing it all wrong.

Comment: @adamp and @Rollin_s, I looked at the Layout Parameters for the Relative Layout. I think I could work with the _alignRight and _alignLeft and _alignBottom to make my buttons move to where they need to be, however I would like to set the button a little higher than the absolute bottom of the screen. I may be able to do this by making the button bigger to just cover the regions that I need. Is this a correct view on this? I am going to add a screenshot of my image to the original post to help clarify.

Comment: I couldn't add the image since I am new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit funky but if all youve got to work with is a flattened image of the equivalent iPhone UI and the only UI elements you need to add are buttons over top of it, I might be tempted to try the following alternative to the tedious work of trying to get the transparent buttons to align:

- Determine where your button locations are relative to your normal/unscaled image, record the top, left, bottom, right values in some data structure of your choosing
- Place your image in an ImageView set to scale using FitXY
- calculate the scaling that android has applied to your image by examining the ImageViews H & W and comparing to what your native image H & W were
- do some math to scale the top,left,bottom, and right values from your original values
- Then in an onClick handler for your image view you should be able to test to see if the touched coordinates are within any of the scaled boundaries you've now got.

Probably would be more accurate, easier to maintain, and less hassle than fiddling with the layout stuff.

Of course, the more correct solution would be to get the actual individual graphic elements used to do the iPhone app and re-implement the UI in android proper.

Good luck.